# Ubuntu Phone hangs when receiving a text-message (sms)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

Since last week I'm having problems with my phone E4.5.  When I receive a text-message , the phone hangs (or crashes, I can't really say).  The green led is still blinking but I cannot shut the phone done, nor reset it.  I just have to wait until the battery runs out and then it starts back up when given power.  Today I received a phone call and while listening to the mailbox (I was to late to answer :-) ) the phone just stopped working.

Comment: Yes that happens to BQ4.5 ocassionally, I'm able to shut down (long hold power button) and the good news is, the recieved SMS which caused the crash is still there!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bug report on launchpad.net:
[Shell not responsive after an incoming SMS or call notification](https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1491566)
Which seems identical to your issue here.

It's opened against Meizu MX4, but user reported that it's also affecting BQ E4.5 (comment #2).

Please click on the "**This bug affects # people. Does this bug affect you?**" string and subscribe to this bug to get updated on this issue.

Comment: OK , did it.  I also contacted the support of BQ itself about the issue and they gave me the tip to reset the phone by pressing the power button about 30 seconds or all 3 buttons (volume + - ) for 30 seconds.  Afterwards the phone restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's another case of the phone slowing down (maybe to the point where it becomes irresponsive) due to crashes + sending the crashes report. Maybe taking a look to the errors sent gives you some clue of what might be happening.